# Adding text to RichTextBox in new form in 

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, let's call them `Main` and `Form2`.
`Main` form consists of a button and `Form2` consists of a `RichTextBox`.

What I want my program to do is when I click button in the main form it calls function in class `DoSomeWork.Do()`. Function `Do()` gets some text from file, it has to open `Form2` and paste this text to that `RichTextBox`.

Problem is that I don't know how to "access" this RichTextBox and paste text to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a property on form 2

```
public string RichTextboxText 
{
    get
    {
        return this.RichTextBox1.Text
    }
    set
    {
        this.RichTextBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Then create a new form:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2() { RichtTextBoxText = "I like big butts"; } 
f2.Show();
```

Something like this should works

[edit]

just like to add that in this way you can also get the value back to from one.

in form one at any random point you can do:

```
string RichtEditTextFromForm2 = f2.RichTextBoxText;
```

given f2 is still active atleast

Comment: I totally forgot about it :( Thx

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: Dont edit my text.. it's a song! ==> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ImZTwYwCug

Answer (score 0):

In Form2 you add a method

```
public void InsertText(string text)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = text;
}
```

to use the method you open Form2 like this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.InsertText("hello world");
f2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass text values through `Constructor`.

Eg:
   create `parameterised constructor` for Form2

```
Public  Form2(string str)
       {
         this.Value=str;
         InitializeComponent();
        }
```

**NOTE:**  `Value` is a public string in form `Form2` .and you can set this value to richTextBox in `form loading`.

```
richTextBox1.Text=Value;
```